# How to get reference of a reusable children component that has mat-paginator inside in Angular 9

Tags: angular, pagination

I've created a `mat-table` component from material design that is reusable along with another `mat-paginator` component.

From a component view, I use both separately. But I wish I could get the reference of these 2 components so I can ViewChild each of them, table for the matSort and paginator for the pagination.

If I do the following:

`<custom-paginator #paginator .... />`

To then retrieve it as:

```
@ViewChild('paginator') paginator: MatPaginator
```

this.paginator has the reference but throws exception on console `TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected...` maybe  because I'm not setting the reference directly to the mat-paginator but to a custom component ?

This is my paginator code at the moment:

```
<mat-paginator
    [length]="length"
    [pageSize]="pageSize"
    [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"
    (page)="pageChange($event)">
</mat-paginator>
```

And this is how I use it:

```
<paginator-widget
   #paginator
   [length]="dataSource?.filteredData.length"
   pageSize="25"
   (page)="handlePageChange($event)">
</paginator-widget>
```

Same I need to do with my custom mat-table, how can I get access to the reference so I can set it to dataSource? Using Angular 9 and Mat 9.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error you are getting doesn't sound to be related to ViewChild issue.

`paginator` type will be your paginator-widget component, not **MatPaginator**.

You could add `@ViewChild` to paginator widget:

`@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;`

And from parent access it in PaginatorWidgetComponent instance:

```
@ViewChild('paginator') paginatorWidget: PaginatorWidgetComponent;    
...
console.log(this.paginatorWidget.paginator)
```

Comment: You're the boss! this is exactly what i needed!